# UWP: Visual Studio requires a newer version to display this content

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2022

I use Visual Studio Professional 2022. When I try to display XAML files I see this error:

[image: Visual Studio requires a newer version of Windows to display this content. Please update to Windows 11, version 22H2 (10.0.22621.0) or later.]

I installed older SDKs in my VS installer:

[image: installed older SDKs- Windows 10SKD (10.0.20348.0)]

And I changed the target platform version in project properties:

[image: Target Platform version is 10.0.18362.0]

But the error is still there. Is there any way to force Visual Studio to refresh it an finally 'click'?

Comment: It sounds like VS 2022 needs Windows 11 to display this tool and it's not dependant upon the project's target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio resolved the issue.